# c# add item to list in object in list of objects

Tags: c#, list

I've tried to work like: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791824/add-item-to-propertylist-object-type-in-list-object-c-sharp)

Got an object class:

```
class Letter
{
    public char letter {get; set;}
    public List<int> posities { get; set; }

    public Letter()
    {
        posities = new List<int>();
    }
    
}
```

and want to add an int to the positions list by:

```
 letters.Add(new Letter
            {
                letter = a,
                posities.Add(i)                   
            });
```

But can't get it working, what am I doing wrong??
(btw: the letter a is added like expected, the problem is with adding the positie i).

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Also read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers .

Comment: "But can't get it working" Why not, what is the problem or the error?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it says: "The name posities does not exist in the current context. Invalid initializer member declarator"

Comment: letter = a,
                posities.Add(i)  What is a and i ?

Comment: @serge a is an char and i is an integer, that are procuced earlier in the code, but wanted to keep it a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Goodquestion why not add another constructor to your letter class, which simply takes `a` and `i` as arguments and correctly adds them to the respective properties?

Comment: `but wanted to keep it a minimal reproducible example.` Minimal, perhaps. Reproducible - definitely not.

Comment: Letter object should be initialized beforehand to access posties list object, in your code you are initilalizing posties in constructor which context will be ready after Letter object initialized.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use = to assign something when you use  an object initializers - you can only set properties or fields, rather than call methods.

```
void Main()
{
    var a='a';
    var i=1;
    var letters = new List<Letter>();
    letters.Add(new Letter
    {
        letter = a,
        posities = new List<int> { i }
    });
    
}
```

otherwise maybe you will have to create a special constructor

```
    public Letter(char letter, int i)
    {
        letter=a;
        posities = new List<int> {i};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know why but this IS working:

```
letters.Add(new Letter
            {
                letter = a,                
            });

            letters[0].posities.Add(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets rewrite your last code in order to clarify

```
var a = 'c';
var i = 0;
var letters = new List<Letter>(); 
var letter = new Letter();//Letter's constructor called and posties list initialized after that you can access posties member functions, like 'Add'
letter = a;
letter.posties.Add(i);
letters.Add(letter);
```

There are too many ways to write code, try to stay clear and do not put all the eggs in the same basket.